# gluonfx nativePackage for Android

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon, graalvm-native-image

How do i enable multiDex for classes so they can be included or traced on the DexPathList?

I am using graalvm (with native-image) and gluonfx nativePackage task to generate the apk.

```
id 'com.gluonhq.gluonfx-gradle-plugin' version '1.0.3' //build.gradle
```

but when I try to access an SMS BroadcastReceiver, I get Class not found in the DexPathList ...

this is the androidManifest setup ..

```
     <application ... package="demo"   ...>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
        <receiver android:name=".services.SmsListener" 
                  android:enabled="true" 
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
     </application>
```

and the error i get when an sms drops on the phone  is as below ..
**Unable to instantiate receiver demo.services.SmsListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "demo.services.SmsListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/.../base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/...-g==/lib/arm64, /data/app/..g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]**

So how go I pass MultiDexEnabled True  to android task? or
Is there a way i can start this broadcast class through java code?
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLSSL.png)

Comment: Where did you create `demo.services.SmsListener`? After you do `mvn gluonfx:package` you have the Android project under `target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project`. You can modify it, but then you need to package it again manually (with `./gradlew AssembleDebug`).

Comment: the demo.services.SmsListener.java is under the src/android/java folder of the main project.  Indeed after ./gradlew nativeBuild and ./gradle nativePackage I can see build/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project along side my demo.apk (which is generated after the native image creation) file . So how do I modify now the android_project (so it updates the same demo.apk to include such SmsListener) on the classes.dex or classes2.dex files inside the demo.apk).

Comment: There is no automatic way so far. You have to modify manually the `android_project`, adding your Android sources and changing the manifest if needed, and then build the apk again with `./gradlew AssembleDebug`. After that you can use `nativeInstall` and `nativeRun`.

Comment: Thx José .. I have attached the project structure. by adding android sources in the android_project, how will I link the generated lib.so of the project (as it has code to process and display the sms) from the Listener. I deleted the apk (which deploys and runs well on the phone) and run AssembleDebug and it didn't even create the apk. Is there any sample I can follow...

Comment: One thing is adding Android code and getting it into the APK (that can be done easily as I described before). The problem is getting it to communicate with the Java/JavaFX layer, as that requires two different VMs talking into each other (GraalVM/Java and Android/Java). For this case, the best option is to follow the [Gluon Attach](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach) services implementation. I'll try to post a possible solution.

Comment: Gluon Attach would definitely be BETTER (since the service would be Incorporated within the native-image communication).. If I can get a notification of the SMS so i can filter or process its contents. I will be waiting for you possible solution.  Thx

Comment: I've created this experimental repository: https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach. It has a dummy `LogService` to show how a custom service can be created for desktop, iOS and Android. Can you give it a try and see if you can use the `LogService` on your Android project? Then you could refactor it to create the `SMSService`.

Comment: The LogService build was successful. I am using ``` implementation 'org.jpereda.attach:log:4.0.12-SNAPSHOT' ``` . I can use the LogService.class in the main project and when i try nativeBuild task, I get Execution failed for task ':mobile:nativeCompile'.                                                                                                
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':mobile:runtimeClasspath'.                                                                       
   > Could not find com.gluonhq.attach:util:4.0.12-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: LogService depends on `com.gluonhq.attach:util:4.0.12-SNAPSHOT`. Since it is a snapshot, you need to add a repo with this url: `"https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"` to your pom.

Comment: See my comment :)

Comment: Dear José, nativeBuild, nativePacke, nativeInstall all success but app now does't popup the welcome screen!!.  How do I import the LogService to be part of the gluonfx attachConfig ???.  Services.get(LogService.class).ifPresent(service -> service.log("application init started ...")); I think there is something I am doing wrongly... kindly some more guidance

Comment: You don't add it to `attachConfig`, as it is not an "official" Attach service. You need to treat it as a regular dependency. See https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach#how-to-build-and-install-attach

Comment: Desktop(runtimeOnly 'org.jpereda.attach:log:4.0.12-SNAPSHOT:desktop): Is now running ok. I can see the log info ...,  Android apk (with gradle dependency runtimeOnly 'org.jpereda.attach:log:4.0.12-SNAPSHOT:android'). I get error ... AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "substrateGetStatusBarServiceClass" referenced by "/data/app/~~Nce0oi3TWB1fpMlJvqMSdQ==/demo.mobile-ec2Wcm1WeXkaSpeHC2pc_A==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so"...

Comment: With the recent [change](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/commit/0081d3708dcbb9b5e088c494104caffe0d625381) in Attach there is no more `substrateGetStatusBarServiceClass` and similar symbols, so you need to make sure you use Attach services with version 4.0.12-SNAPSHOT, not lower.

Comment: AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol '__android_log_print' referenced by .../lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so ..  could I be doing something wrong with gradle dependence runtimeOnly 'org.jpereda.attach:log:4.0.12-SNAPSHOT:android' ???

Comment: That is a function defined in `android/log.h` that is part of Android NDK, which is [required](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach/blob/master/gradle/native-build.gradle#L347) to build the services. What is your `ANDROID_NDK`?

Comment: Hmm, that is used as well by Substrate and the regular Attach services, and  using the gluonfx plugin you've already built, deployed and run successfully APKs on your Android device, haven't you?

Comment: Pkg.Desc = Android NDK
Pkg.Revision = 21.3.6528147

Comment: Yes.  the apk am testing is deployed on the emulator (must as it was working on the phone).  Should I install the latest NDK and re-build the attach service?

Comment: Can you do a new test on Android with [HelloGluon](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloGluon) for instance, but with Attach 4.0.12-SNAPSHOT only?

Comment: was doing the same testing on phone... Yes. I see the log being printed (via adb log ..).  wow!!

Comment: José Thx for everything so far(though  thread is becoming long!! ..). so now back to the start of detecting and receipt of the SMS.. I beg you don't be tired of me

Comment: No problem, glad it works for you now. I should write a proper answer on how to create a custom Attach service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial question is about adding Java code to the Android sources, before packaging the project into the final APK.

### Modifying the Android project

Since there is no automatic procedure from the gluonfx plugin yet, it is a manual process:

- Run `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build gluonfx:package` once, that will create the Android project under `target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project`.
- Add the Java/Android sources to `target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/app/src/main/java`
- Build manually the APK:

  ```
  cd target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/
  export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/.gluon/substrate/Android
  ./gradlew app:assembleDebug
  ```
- Continue the process: `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:install gluonfx:run`

While this allows modifying the Android part, the main caveat is the lack of communication from this side to the Java/JavaFX/GraalVM part, so it will only work in case it is an isolated modification on the Android side.

### Creating a custom Attach service

In order to modify the Android part and also get access to the Java/JavaFX side, the best approach is to create an [Attach](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach) service.

For this, one option is to clone Attach, add the new service, and publish/distribute this modified version of Attach, but better is to create just a custom Attach service outside of Attach.

#### LogService

This experimental [repository](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach) contains a new service: `LogService`, just as proof of concept.

The [readme](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach#custom-attach) already contains instructions on how to get started and use this service.

##### Build the service

To summarise:

- Make sure you follow the [requisites](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach#requisites)
- Clone the repository
- Build and publish to local: `./gradlew clean publishToMavenLocal`.
- Make sure you have the artifacts under `~/.m2/repository/org/jpereda/attach/log/4.0.12-SNAPSHOT`:

```
   log-4.0.12-SNAPSHOT-android.jar
   log-4.0.12-SNAPSHOT-ios.jar 
   log-4.0.12-SNAPSHOT-desktop.jar
   log-4.0.12-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

##### Use LogService in your project

Assuming you are running [HelloGluon](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloGluon):

###### pom

Add the dependency to the pom. Note that the official Attach dependencies remain the same, but you will need 4.0.12-SNAPSHOT.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpereda.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>log</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Notice that since it is not an official Attach service, it can't use the package name `com.gluonhq.attach`, and it can't be added to the `attachList`. Therefore, it is treated as a regular dependency, and you need to add the platform dependency based on the target:

For instance, for Android:

```
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jpereda.attach</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <classifier>android</classifier>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

###### code

From your code, call the service as usual:

```
LogService.create().ifPresent(service -> service.log("This is a message"));
```

##### Test the service

For instance, on Android:

```
mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build gluonfx:package gluonfx:install gluonfx:nativerun
```

#### Create your own service

First of all, read https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_device_interface for a better understanding of an Attach service.

Following the `LogService` [project](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach/tree/master/modules/log) it should be more or less straightforward to create your own service.

The more complex part is in the communication between Java(11+)/JavaFX/GraalVM and Java(7)/Android, where JNI is required. The Java side is AOT compiled and goes into `lib${service}.a` and the Android side goes to the Android project and distributed as `${service}>.aar`, without JavaFX support.

Comment: GraalCompile : Fatal error: Current target does not support the following CPU features that are required by the image: [FP, ASIMD].

Comment: I take your target is Android? That has been solved a while ago for iOS and Linux AArch64, but was not needed for Android. What is your GraalVM version?

Comment: while under src/main/native/android/dalvik/DalvikLogService.class, I was trying to call a native method in class  but System.loadLibrary("log"); cant load the library couldn't find "liblog.so". In Attach, where should the lib be loaded from? (under src/main/java/.... ?). Also indeed the lib{service}.so file is not found... have been following the earlier comments (unless if am missing some step again)

Comment: GraalVM verison: am using your graalvm-svm-linux-gluon-21.2.0-dev

Comment: I'm not following... Are you testing my [LogService](https://github.com/jperedadnr/Custom-Attach) and that fails? Didn't you report earlier that eventually it worked for you? Or is it only after you apply some changes?

Comment: ooooh sorry... LogService is perfect.  its my libsms.so that i can't load. I have got the sms under DalvikSmsService. and want to push it to graal. so under DalvikSmsService I created ```native static void processReceivedSms(String key, String value);```  with sms.c having my line like ... ```JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_gluonhq_helloandroid_DalvikSmsService_processReceivedSms (JNIEnv *env, jobject service, jstring jkey, jstring jvalue){.. I get the error No implementation found for void com.gluonhq.helloandroid.DalvikSmsService.processReceivedSms(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: Ok, this is getting complex... My answer was a little bit generic for your specific question, but it sets a common ground for creating custom services. I'd say that you should create a new post, you can refer to this one. It will be way  easier for adding your code and issues.

Comment: @user16575954 I see you have a new post, great. In order to have this post resolved, you could mark the answer as accepted, as it might be of some value for others too?