# Can a JavaFX project built with Gluon be opened in Android Studio for further modification?

Tags: android-studio, gluon-mobile

Can a project that is built with JavaFX Gluon (and say, saved on github) be forked and opened by Android Studio for further modifications?

Comment: What is your purpose? If you want to edit the Java/JavaFX source you need a Java IDE. If you deploy to Android, you can edit the final Android project before building the APK, but that has limited options.

Comment: I would like to make use of the AAudio functionality on Android, while using JavaFX for the other aspects of the GUI. As far as I can tell, triggering events from audio, such as .onRepeat() for MediaPlayer cycles entails a great deal of latency, possibly because the .onRepeat argument has to launch a runnable, and can't be used to execute a method that simply flips a boolean without the thread management overhead.

Comment: @JoséPereda Where can I learn more about what these "limited options" are that you refer to?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68623490/gluonfx-nativepackage-for-android