# Gluon Google Play android target api fails

Tags: android, package, google-play, gluon

On uploading .aab to Google Play, it fails because the latest API is not being used.  Google wants to see API 31 not 30. I thought this was starting in November but apparently the requirement is already there for new apps.  I tried to set the targetSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest file but gluonfx:package fails with:

```
The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig in the build.gradle file.
```

There are two build.gradle files that I can find and the one with defaultConfig is in ../gvm/android_project.  I edited the defaultConfig in this to targetSdkVersion 31 but gluonfx:package changes this back to 30.  Presumably this build.gradle is being generated from somewhere.

What should I do to get the required targetSdkVersion to be 31.

Comment: If you are not using Attach (see [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/issues/328)), you can manually run the package goal. See for reference "Modifying the Android project" from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68685263/3956070).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't really understand that process.  I don't know gradle that well so your suggestions were not obvious to me.  This: `cd target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/.gluon/substrate/Android
./gradlew app:assembleDebug` is presumably the core to a manual build, but I do not want to build with debug.  What app:"goals(?)" are there to build the .aab without debug?  Plus, do I still edit build.gradle to have the targetSdkVersion at 31?

Comment: Yes, edit the build.gradle file, do the changes, save, and then you can run `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`.

Comment: This still does not work.  To start, with Android target of 12,  `android:exported="true"` has to be added to the Activity tag of the AndroidManifest.  I then edit the build.gradle `defaultConfig{}` to have `targetSdkVersion 31`.  I then run `./gradlew app:assembleRelease` as suggested - but it still generates an apk with its manifest stating `targetSdkVersion 30`!  How can I get to see what is in assembleRelease such that it insists on 30?  What should I do now to get this app onto Google Play??

Comment: You can try now GluonFX `1.0.16-SNAPSHOT` with Attach `4.0.16-SNAPSHOT`, by adding a `pluginRepository` with this URL to the pom: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots. There is no need of a manual process.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that.  When you say Attach `4.0.16-SNAPSHOT`, does this include the Attach list stuff: device, connectivity, display etc.?  Because the build barfs when I just change the Attach version to `4.0.16-SNAPSHOT`.  Otherwise what is the dependency I should include for `4.0.16-SNAPSHOT'?

Comment: Right, you also need to add a `repository` to the pom with the same URL.

Comment: Brilliant!  Many thanks, .aab uploaded successfully.

Comment: Cool, if you have any issue about these changes, feel free to report it to https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/issues or https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues