# Where to specify namespace when packaging an android app through gluon

Tags: android, javafx, gluon

When trying to package an android app using Gluon (mvn gluonfx:package -Pandroid) I face the following error:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> Error while evaluating property 'applicationId' of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'applicationId'.
> > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
> > Package Name not found in /home/argentum/myApp/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, and namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace for the generated R and BuildConfig classes via android.namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

```
       android {
           namespace 'com.example.namespace'
       }
```

I'm not too familiar with android and gradle but I tried to create the build.gradle file and specified the namespace as the error suggested but this made no difference. Where am I meant to specify the namespace?

I've consulted https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android_distribution_manifest and https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace but I wasn't able to find the answer.

Comment: If you edit the build file under `/home/argentum/myApp/target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/app/`, you can't run `mvn gluonfx:package` again, as it will ignore your changes. You need to manually package your app. See for instance the first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68685263/3956070) answer for that.